# How to deal with elasticsearch range Beetween 2 dates

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have the following mapping:

```html
'contract' => [
    'type' => 'nested',
    'include_in_parent' => true,
    'properties' => [
        'started_at' => ['type' => 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'],
        'ended_at' => ['type' => 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'],
    ],
],
```

I'm trying to write a query that searches for all active contracts; **a contract is active when now is between `started_at` and `anded_at`, or `started_at < now` if the contract is undetermined (`ended_at is null`)**.

my try was the following, but still doesn't handle both the cases:

```html
'bool' => [
    'must' => [
        ['range' => ['applications.contract.started_at' => ['lte' => 'now']]],
        ['range' => ['applications.contract.ended_at' => ['gte' => 'now']]],
    ],
],
```

Any hint would be awesome, thanks folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have "nullable" field as "ended_at" you need to combine "range" and "must_not" into "should" because elasticsearch does not index NULL value (as a result it's a missing field)

So your query will look something like this:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
            {
                "range": {"applications.contract.started_at": {"lte": "now"}}
            },
            "should": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "applications.contract.ended_at": {"gte": "now"}
                    }
                },
     
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must_not": {
                            "exists": "applications.contract.ended_at"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

also, I've noticed that you are using "nested" documents so the query above must be wrapped into a nested query

```json
{
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "contract",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {"applications.contract.started_at": {"lte": "now"}}
                        }
                        ],
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "applications.contract.ended_at": {"gte": "now"}
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "must_not": {
                                        "exists": {"field": "applications.contract.ended_at"}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `path` should be `applications.contract`